# Access windows server information( like System.IO) from a local machine

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

I am trying to make a console application in which I am trying to get the drive information from the local machine using System.IO. Now I want to get the same information for a server from my local machine, how do I do that? How do I connect to it? and After Connection how do I access its Windows system logs(Administration/Computer Management)? I know one thing that the servers can be accessed through UNC path(\servername\name\dir) but If I want to access the server disk spaces(using System.IO) and error logs how do I do that?
I already have username and passwords for it.
Any help on this is most welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WMI). In .NET, you access it through classes in the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.

You can also connect to remote machine event logs using the [System.Diagnostics.EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class. There are some good examples in the documentation.

You might also get some relevant information using performance counters. See [PerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.aspx) and related classes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jim, yeah I think you are right,I'll try to implement the WMI in my application and see how it goes. Thanks again for the reply!